# Ace Editor Get Current Cursor Row and Column

Tags: javascript, ace-editor, text-cursor

I'm using Ace Editor. In Javascript, (not jQuery), how would I return the current cursor row and column position?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`editor.getCursorPosition()` returns an object with row and column properties

Comment: That's great, thank you. I was close! :)
So editor.getCursorPosition().row and editor.getCursorPosition().column returns the two figures..?

Comment: For this and all other API calls on the Selection portion of it (as well is all others really) https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=selection - getCursor section

Comment: In case you need to monitor the cursor position, use: `editor.session.selection.on('changeCursor', function(){});`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the function that will get you the object.

```
getCursor() //The name of this function it may have been changed - this is a current one as of September 2016
```

It returns a Position Object that consists of two members:

```
row
column
```

Ways to use it are:

```
var iRowPosition;
var iColumnPosition;

var oPositionObject;

oPositionObject = InstanceOfYourEditor.selection.getCursor(); // to get the Position Object
iRowPosition = InstanceOfYourEditor.selection.getCursor().row; // to get the Row Position 
iColumnPosition = InstanceOfYourEditor.selection.getCursor().column; // to get the Column Position
```

Let's say you want want to pass this object as a parameter to some other function such as:

```
InstanceOfYourEditor.selection.insert() //accepts Position Object and a text to insert
```

then you can just pass the Object as is

```
InstanceOfYourEditor.selection.insert(oPositionObject, "Just Want To Provide A More Detailed Answer So My Fellows Can Better Visualize It All");
```

This answer was more of "fishing for you" - but I encourage you to learn how to fish in general and specifically with Ace Editor object by referring to the Ace Editor API that contains all the information about the object.

[ACE EDITOR API - Selection Section](https://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=selection)